How to show the popup above the table - Tailwindcss and Alpine Js
When you click the filter icon in the table, a popup window appears. If the table has a lot of rows, everything looks fine. But if there are only 1 or 2 rows in the table, the popup gets hidden into the table. You can check the image for a clearer idea.
What I expect is, If I click the filter icon, that popup window fully shows over the table



<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.13.5/cdn.js"
        integrity="sha512-8IPRU0MPrge2KfSxkAtO8pIkaMzThW/MBSvPqcyVisSymLWC986buo27pKAt5mWXmt58dT6jIsw7h8NNugtRwg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer></script>

</head>
<body class="p-4">
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll">
            <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
                <thead
                    class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
                    <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
                        <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">In Time</th>

                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                            Out Time</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Break Time">
                            B.T</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Working Hours">
                            W.H</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                            <div class="flex gap-2 item-center">
                                <p>Status</p>
                                <div class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                                    <button @click="open = !open">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                            viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor"
                                            class="w-4 h-4">
                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                                d="M12 3c2.755 0 5.455.232 8.083.678.533.09.917.556.917 1.096v1.044a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-.659 1.591l-5.432 5.432a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659 1.591v2.927a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-1.244 2.013L9.75 21v-6.568a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659-1.591L3.659 7.409A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 3 5.818V4.774c0-.54.384-1.006.917-1.096A48.32 48.32 0 0 1 12 3Z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    <div x-show="open" @click.away="open = false"
                                        class="absolute right-0 z-10 w-48 p-4 text-xs text-center bg-white border rounded-md shadow-lg top-6">
                                        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">All</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Present</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="notInRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.notInRadio.checked = true">Not
                                                    In</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="leaveRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer "
                                                    @click="$refs.leaveRadio.checked = true">Paid
                                                    Leave</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="leaveRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer "
                                                    @click="$refs.leaveRadio.checked = true">Unpaid
                                                    Leave</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="weekOffRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.weekOffRadio.checked = true">Weekoff</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="publicHolidayRadio"
                                                    type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.publicHolidayRadio.checked = true">Public
                                                    Holiday</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pt-4">
                                                <button
                                                    class="w-1/2 px-2 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 rounded">Apply</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Include other radio options similarly -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>

                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                            <div class="flex gap-2 item-center">
                                <p>Sub Status</p>
                                <div class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                                    <div class="relative">
                                        <button @click="open = !open">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                                viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                                                stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4">
                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                                    d="M12 3c2.755 0 5.455.232 8.083.678.533.09.917.556.917 1.096v1.044a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-.659 1.591l-5.432 5.432a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659 1.591v2.927a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-1.244 2.013L9.75 21v-6.568a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659-1.591L3.659 7.409A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 3 5.818V4.774c0-.54.384-1.006.917-1.096A48.32 48.32 0 0 1 12 3Z" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="absolute -top-0.5 -right-1">
                                            <div class="w-2.5 h-2.5 bg-yellow-400 rounded-full"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div x-show="open" @click.away="open = false"
                                        class="absolute right-0 z-10 p-4 text-xs text-center bg-white border rounded-md shadow-lg w-96 top-6">
                                        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4">
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">All</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Late
                                                    Entry</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Early
                                                    Out</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Forgot
                                                    Out</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Short
                                                    Hours</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Paid
                                                    Halfday Leave</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Unpaid
                                                    Halfday Leave</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Break
                                                    Hours</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Working
                                                    Hours</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Overtime</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">1.5X
                                                    Present</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                                                <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio"
                                                    class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox">
                                                <span
                                                    class="w-full ml-2 text-left text-gray-600 cursor-pointer"
                                                    @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">2X
                                                    Present</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">

                                            <div class="pt-4">
                                                <button
                                                    class="w-24 px-2 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 rounded">Apply</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Include other radio options similarly -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Overtime">
                            OT</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                            Penalties
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                            <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                                <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                                    src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div>
                                    <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John Doe</a>
                                    <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                                <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 10:00 AM </span>                                
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                                <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 05:00 PM </span>                                
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div>
                                <p>01:30:00</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div>
                                <p>01:30:00</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div>
                                <p>Present</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div>
                                <p>Late Entry</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div>
                                <p>01:30:00</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="p-4">
                            <div>
                                <p>01:30:00</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Your overflox-x-scroll on the wrapper div is causing that behaviour, the popover is considered to expand the div and cause overflow. Since your popover is a child of its target this kind of behaviour is typical. Using a lib like https://floating-ui.com/ will eliminate these kinds of issues

As @Matti Sig pointed out, it is the overflow-x: scroll CSS declaration on the parent element causing the behavior. You could consider using x-teleport to have the pop-up window display outside the overflow-x-scroll parent:


<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.13.5/cdn.js" integrity="sha512-8IPRU0MPrge2KfSxkAtO8pIkaMzThW/MBSvPqcyVisSymLWC986buo27pKAt5mWXmt58dT6jIsw7h8NNugtRwg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body class="p-4">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll">
        <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
          <thead class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
              <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">Name</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">In Time</th>

              <th scope="col" class="p-4">Out Time</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Break Time">B.T</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Working Hours">W.H</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                <div class="flex gap-2 item-center">
                  <p>Status</p>
                  <div class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                    <button @click="open = !open">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 3c2.755 0 5.455.232 8.083.678.533.09.917.556.917 1.096v1.044a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-.659 1.591l-5.432 5.432a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659 1.591v2.927a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-1.244 2.013L9.75 21v-6.568a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659-1.591L3.659 7.409A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 3 5.818V4.774c0-.54.384-1.006.917-1.096A48.32 48.32 0 0 1 12 3Z" />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                    <template x-teleport="body">
                      <div x-show="open" @click.away="open = false" class="absolute right-0 z-10 w-48 p-4 text-xs text-center bg-white border rounded-md shadow-lg top-6">
                        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">All</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Present</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="notInRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.notInRadio.checked = true">Not In</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="leaveRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.leaveRadio.checked = true">Paid Leave</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="leaveRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.leaveRadio.checked = true">Unpaid Leave</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="weekOffRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.weekOffRadio.checked = true">Weekoff</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="publicHolidayRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.publicHolidayRadio.checked = true">Public Holiday</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="pt-4">
                            <button class="w-1/2 px-2 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 rounded">Apply</button>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Include other radio options similarly -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                <div class="flex gap-2 item-center">
                  <p>Sub Status</p>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Overtime">OT</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">Penalties</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr>
              <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                  <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="" />
                  <div>
                    <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John Doe</a>
                    <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 10:00 AM </span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 05:00 PM </span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>Present</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>Late Entry</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



However, you'll notice the pop-up is no longer aligned to the button/heading position anymore. To fix this, you could consider using the Alpine Anchor plugin (though with an x-id work-around since x-teleport does not work directly with the plugin):


<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/anchor@3.13.5/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.13.5/cdn.js" integrity="sha512-8IPRU0MPrge2KfSxkAtO8pIkaMzThW/MBSvPqcyVisSymLWC986buo27pKAt5mWXmt58dT6jIsw7h8NNugtRwg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body class="p-4">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll">
        <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
          <thead class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
              <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">Name</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">In Time</th>

              <th scope="col" class="p-4">Out Time</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Break Time">B.T</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Working Hours">W.H</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                <div class="flex gap-2 item-center">
                  <p>Status</p>
                  <div class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }" x-id="['button']">
                    <button @click="open = !open" :id="$id('button')">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 3c2.755 0 5.455.232 8.083.678.533.09.917.556.917 1.096v1.044a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-.659 1.591l-5.432 5.432a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659 1.591v2.927a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-1.244 2.013L9.75 21v-6.568a2.25 2.25 0 0 0-.659-1.591L3.659 7.409A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 3 5.818V4.774c0-.54.384-1.006.917-1.096A48.32 48.32 0 0 1 12 3Z" />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                    <template x-teleport="body">
                      <div x-show="open" @click.away="open = false" class="absolute right-0 z-10 w-48 p-4 text-xs text-center bg-white border rounded-md shadow-lg top-6" x-anchor="document.getElementById($id('button'))">
                        <div class="flex flex-col text-left">
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">All</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="presentRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.presentRadio.checked = true">Present</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="notInRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.notInRadio.checked = true">Not In</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="leaveRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.leaveRadio.checked = true">Paid Leave</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="leaveRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.leaveRadio.checked = true">Unpaid Leave</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="weekOffRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.weekOffRadio.checked = true">Weekoff</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="inline-flex items-center py-1.5">
                            <input name="status" x-ref="publicHolidayRadio" type="radio" class="w-4 h-4 form-checkbox" />
                            <span class="w-full ml-2 text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" @click="$refs.publicHolidayRadio.checked = true">Public Holiday</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="pt-4">
                            <button class="w-1/2 px-2 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 rounded">Apply</button>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Include other radio options similarly -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                <div class="flex gap-2 item-center">
                  <p>Sub Status</p>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4" title="Overtime">OT</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">Penalties</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr>
              <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                  <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="" />
                  <div>
                    <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John Doe</a>
                    <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 10:00 AM </span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 05:00 PM </span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>Present</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>Late Entry</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div>
                  <p>01:30:00</p>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



